# What is happening in this short script

Tags: java

I'm not exactly sure whats going on, what is it called?

```
      public static void main(String[] args) // Just calls the main class
  {
    new Main();
  }
```

Could main not just be called with Main() on it on, what does the new do, does it create an object?

Comment: It creates a Main object, whatever that may be -- since you've not shown us your Main class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a class named `Main` and you are creating it's new intense. And more over if the `Main` class is `public` then it is placed in a class with name `Main.java`

Comment: Hmm, ok but it seems to be just calling a method, as it has parametres(). The public static void main is inside the main class and i thought it was calling another method that contains the main program. Why is this being done? What does it actually do and what does it mean? Additionally, when you said intense did you mean instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is called creating/defining an object. In Java, variables can be grouped together in convenient bodies called objects. It seems that your project has a class named `Main`, so by doing this, you are making a new *object* of the class `Main`. You can assign the new instance of `Main` (main object) to a variable by doing this:

```
Main m = new Main();
```

And now the variable `m` contains the variables in that class, which can be accessed as an object.

For example, if your `Main` class contains the global variable `x`, you can access it by doing this:

```
m.x
```

Some more information on objects can be found here:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html
```

From the official Oracle docs.